# How to add thread pool in Jetty 9.2.24 HttpClient?

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9, jetty-8

In Jetty 9 the `setThreadPool` method of `HttpClient` has been removed. Can anyone suggest an alternative way of doing it in Jetty 9?

This is how I used to do in previous versions of Jetty's `HttpClient`:

```
QueuedThreadPool queuedThreadpool= new QueuedThreadPool(5);
queuedThreadpool.setMinThreads(2);
queuedThreadpool.setName("HttpClient");

httpClient.setThreadPool(queuedThreadpool); // <<<<<<
httpClient.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you need to use `setExecutor(executor)`. A `QueuedThreadPool` implements the `Executor` interface.

```
QueuedThreadPool queuedThreadpool= new QueuedThreadPool(5);
queuedThreadpool.setMinThreads(2);
queuedThreadpool.setName("HttpClient");

httpClient.setExecutor(queuedThreadpool);
httpClient.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.